# Screen alerts in Acrobat stopping VBA code

Tags: excel, vba, acrobat

I have this VBA code that searches through PDF files on my computer. Here is the code:

```
Option Explicit

Sub FindTextInPDF()


    Dim TextToFind  As String
    Dim PDFPath     As String
    Dim App         As Object
    Dim AVDoc       As Object
    Dim DS As Worksheet
    Dim SS As Worksheet
    Set DS = Sheets("Report")
    Set SS = Sheets("Search Index")
    Dim sslastrow As Long
    Dim dslastrow As Long
    Dim b As Integer
    Dim J As Integer


    With SS
        sslastrow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
    End With

    With DS
        dslastrow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    End With

    For b = 2 To dslastrow
    PDFPath = "C:\Users\desposito\Documents\Temp\" & 
    Sheets("Report").Range("E" & b).Value & Sheets("Report").Range("B" & 
    b).Value & ".pdf"

    If Dir(PDFPath) = "" Then
        GoTo nextb
    End If

    If LCase(Right(PDFPath, 3)) <> "pdf" Then
        GoTo nextb

    End If

    On Error Resume Next

    Set App = CreateObject("AcroExch.App")

    If Err.Number <> 0 Then

        Set App = Nothing
        GoTo nextb
    End If

    Set AVDoc = CreateObject("AcroExch.AVDoc")

    If Err.Number <> 0 Then

        Set AVDoc = Nothing
        Set App = Nothing
        GoTo nextb
    End If

   On Error GoTo 0

    If AVDoc.Open(PDFPath, "") = True Then

        AVDoc.BringToFront

        Else

        App.Exit

        Set AVDoc = Nothing
        Set App = Nothing

        GoTo nextb

    End If

    For J = 2 To sslastrow
    TextToFind = SS.Range("B" & J).Value


    If AVDoc.FindText(TextToFind, False, False, True) = False Then
        GoTo NextJ
        Else:
        DS.Range("Q" & b).Value = DS.Range("Q" & b).Value & TextToFind & ";"                                 
        & " "  

    End If
    NextJ:
           Next

            AVDoc.Close True


            App.Exit


            Set AVDoc = Nothing
            Set App = Nothing

nextb:

Next

End Sub
```

However, every 100ish files, I will get this notification:

> "Reader has finished searching the document. No matches were found."

All I have to do is hit enter and then the code runs for another 10-30 minutes before I get the notification again. It seems to be randomly happening in the middle of searching through the document which is this part of the code:

```
    For J = 2 To sslastrow
TextToFind = SS.Range("B" & J).Value


If AVDoc.FindText(TextToFind, False, False, True) = False Then
    GoTo NextJ
    Else:
    DS.Range("Q" & b).Value = DS.Range("Q" & b).Value & TextToFind & ";"                                 
    & " "

End If
NextJ:
```

I looked into disabling screen alerts in acrobat, but it doesn't look like I can do that.

Comment: This is exactly why you shouldn't use desktop applications for automation. There are dozens of PDF library tools that will let you search PDF without requiring Acrobat.

Comment: @joelgeraci I am learning this the hard way... but at least I'm learning. I am just going to bulk convert all of my .pdf files to .docx and do the search there since I already have code to do everything else for me. If anything, I just hope this post stops someone else from going down this hole.